# Simple python function throws error when compiled using Numba UnsupportedError: Use of unknown opcode 'MAP_ADD'

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have built a simple feature-normalisation function which I have used for machine learning projects in the past that I am looking to speed up the runtime using Numba. The function normalises grouped data by computing the distance of each value from the kth value in the group (when k=1, this is equivalent to distance from the group maximum).

The function operates as expected when run without using Numba to compile it, but generates the following error when Numba is called:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-2164f054b397>", line 2, in <module>
    norm = distanceFromK(groups, data, 1)

  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\envs\tf4\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 423, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

  File "C:\Users\[username]\anaconda3\envs\tf4\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 361, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)

UnsupportedError: Use of unknown opcode 'MAP_ADD'
```

Any idea what is causing this and how it can be fixed? Example code below:

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def distanceFromK(groupIds, values, k):
    n = len(groupIds)
    dat = np.zeros(n)
    # create a dict to track the max, 2nd max,..., kth max values in each group
    d = {gid:{i:-1000000 for i in range(1,k+1)} for gid in groupIds}
    
    # loop through each value
    for i in range(n):
        gid, val = groupIds[i], values[i]
        # loop through ranks
        for m in reversed(range(1,k+1)):
            # check whether value ranks high enough to be added to dict
            if val > d[gid][m] and m > 1:
                # if yes, displace existing value and continue moving to higher ranks
               d[gid][m] = d[gid][m-1]
               m -= 1
            else:
                # correct rank has been reached. update value in dict and break loop
                d[gid][m] = val
                break
    # loop through data a second time, computing distance of each value to the desired rank
    for i in range(n):
        gid, val = groupIds[i], values[i]
        dat[i] = val - d[gid][k]
    return dat

n = 500000
k = 5000
groupIds = list(range(k))
groups = np.array(list(np.random.choice(groupIds, n)))
data = np.random.rand(n)

norm_data = distanceFromK(groups, data, 1)
```

Comment: Is that the full error message?  nothing to tell you/us where the problem is?  I'm not an expert in `numba`, but my impression is that it is better suited to handling `numpy` arrays than Python `list` and `dict`.  Especially with the `nopython=True` specification.  How is it supposed to handle generic Python objects in a nopython mode?

Comment: Have included the full error message, although I didn't find anything that would be helpful in pinpointing the cause of the problem

Answer (score 2):

Currently, numba does not support dict comprehensions. See [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html)